# Developer tools to directly access databases

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, eclipse, oracle

I work with several different databases and find myself trying connecting to these quite often to test a query. I use the database specific tools to connect to the DB and run the query.

I find these DB specific tools like SQL Query Analyzer (SQL-Server), Oracle Enterprise Manager, MySQL Query Browser to be quite clunky and slow when it comes to running quick queries and looking at data directly. It is also hard to remember all the userids and pwds for the develop and test databases.

What tools do you use as developers to connect to the database of choice? I use Eclipse as an IDE. So any Eclipse specific tips are also appreciated.

Even if a tool were to work with one DB and not with the other, I am willing to look into it if it were more user-friendly than the one the DB vendor provides. I am already using 3 different ones.

Comment: https://github.com/sqlectron

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[SQuirreL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/), written in java, will work with any RDBMS for which there's a JDBC driver.

It works very well for both sending SQL, rendering result sets, and allowing browsing of database objects (from a tree). For several RDBMS, it includes extensions to automatically generate common statements.

Especially nice is that the query pane executes either the selected sql, or the line the cursor is on up to the first blank line. This allows you to write several statements, and to execute them either individually or in a batch.

And it's free and open source.

Comment: I have started using this and it seems to be just perfect for what I was trying to do. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah it's sweet. Unfortunately I don't use it myself any more, as it has too many panes with too many toolbars to work well on my 1024x600 netbook.

Answer (score 9):

I've used quite a few.

- [PL/SQL Developer](http://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html): as the name implies this is Oracle specific but is by far my favourite DB tool. It greatly simplifies import/export;
- [Toad](http://www.toadsoft.com/): Also Oracle-specific. I used to be a big fan of this but it's expensive and I think more DBA-oriented these days. For a developer I don't think it offers all that much (given the price difference) over PL/SQL Developer;
- [DBVisualizer](http://www.minq.se/products/dbvis/): this tool isn't bad. I'm not sure the commercial version is worth the price they're asking for it. The free version is OK. It's good that it works with pretty much any database;
- [Navicat for MySQL](http://www.navicat.com/): it's OK but honestly I wouldn't pay for it;
- [SQL Server management Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en): comes with SQL Server. I don't think I really need much more for SQL Server than this except perhaps a better way of importing/exporting databases, soemthing for which this is garbage;
- [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/index.html): this is the poor man's tool you use on Linux when you don't have much other choice. It's fairly basic but OK given that it's free.

Comment: The free version of DBVisualizer doesn't allow you to run sections of sql scripts - a feature I personally can't live without.

Answer (score 4):

Also a nice tool is the [AquaDataStudio](http://www.aquafold.com/)

Answer (score 2):

I've used:

[TOAD](http://www.toadsoft.com/)

[DBVisualizer](http://www.minq.se/products/dbvis/)

I prefer DBVisualizer, but it's a bit of a memory hog so it might not be the right solution if your resources are an issue.

I've tried the eclipse plugins as well. For me I'd rather keep eclipse optimized to do the work it's meant to do.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to stuff like this, I prefer portable tools. Installed once, you can put them on flash or CD and carry with you. Connecting to DB should be easy as filling out usual fields: server, user, pwd..

[Sql Buddy](http://sqlbuddy.sourceforge.net/)
Decent one, open source, with syntax highlighting & code completition. Not recently updated but it generally works OK.

[GiPo@DB Utilities](http://www.gibinsoft.net/gipoutils/dbutil/content.htm)
Very nice one, has all of the above features plus its more feature filled as it was previously commercial.

Mentioned tools are not more then few MBs in size and it takes 1 minute to install them and copy them to your portable location.

Answer (score 2):

Within Eclipse you can use the [Eclipse Data Tools Platform](http://www.iipt.fr/dtptutor.html) for doing database development. In recent versions you can find some kind of [visual query builder](http://live.eclipse.org/node/678) as well. Oracle has a [plugin for DTP](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14545_01/help/oracle.eclipse.tools.database.doc/html/gettingStarted/files/gettingStarted.html) and implements some Oracle-specific functions.

Answer (score 1):

Database Workbench can be use for Oracle - SQL Server and MySQL

http://www.upscene.com

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [Rapid SQL](http://edn.embarcadero.com/rapid_sql)

it is a cross-platform SQL IDE that helps database and application developers produce high quality SQL code faster.Embarcadero Rapid SQL helps you increase database development efficiency by:

Streamlining SQL coding tasks, object management, reverse-engineering, source code control and schema deployment

Improving team collaboration and resource sharing

Accelerating application development cycles with code assist, Quick Fixes, SQL to Java round-trip debugging, and profiling tools

Standardizing with one tool set with deep cross-DBMS platform support

Answer (score 0):

[Aqua Data Studio](http://www.aquafold.com/) and [RapidSQL](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/rapid_sql/index.php) are two great tools/IDEs for sql development. You can connect almost any database engine and they include some vendor specific features for say Oracle etc..

Also since you use Eclipse IDE, you may consider Eclipse Data Tools Platform or QuantumDB plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The tools depends a bit of the kind of work to do. For most browsing I go for [DbVisualizer](http://dbvis.com), I can customize it exactly to my needs. The support is good and responsive. For pl/sql editing I prefer oracle sqldeveloper.
DbVisualizer is not a free tool but the price is fair, maybe even cheap when compared to Toad. It is also multi database but this is implemented in such a way that I am not limited in my oracle world and it helps me navigating on other vendor rdbms that I don't know so well.
For real time monitoring DbVisualizer has a very nice option that I have not seen in any other application. VERY usable if you are trying to debug some, for example, performance problems.

[Ronald](http://ronr.blogspot.com)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [RazorSQL](http://www.razorsql.com/).  It has all the features of the most expensive tools at a fraction of the price.