# What is the best free SQL GUI for Linux for various DBMS systems

Tags: sql, linux

As I make the full switch from Windows to Linux (CentOS 5) I'm in search of the best free GUI SQL Client tool for MSSQL, MySQL, Oracle, etc... any suggestions?

I've tried DBVisualizer (The best bet so far but still limited by the free version, not all functionality is there), MySQL GUI Tools (Good but only for MySQL, need other DB's as well) and Aqua Data Studio (Same as DBVis, it's good but a lot of the functionality is missing in the free version).

Comment: What do you need from that GUI? Do you need support for coding (e.g. PL/SQL or T-SQL)? Do you need integration with source control? Do you need schema navigation? Do you need support for database diagrams (reverse/forward engineering)?

Comment: Looking for more of the advanced tools such as: Graphing w/ releationship (one to one, one to many, etc...), Trigger feature, multiple query execution at once, etc...

Comment: There is the Falcon Sql client https://github.com/plotly/falcon-sql-client/releases 
that also includes functionality for plotting your data.
Have to add this as comment, because I cannot post a new answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm sticking with DbVisualizer Free until something better comes along.

EDIT/UPDATE: been using https://dbeaver.io/ lately, really enjoying this

Comment: You could try DBeaver or RazorSQL

Comment: You could try Valentina Studio Free

Comment: Sqlectron is free and looks great. Fully cross-platform as well. https://sqlectron.github.io/

Comment: I want to practice my SQL skills, what client do you suggest. dbeaver seems too clumsy.

Answer (score 45):

I can highly recommend [Squirrel SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/).

Also see this similar question:

[Developer tools to directly access databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721852/developer-tools-to-directly-access-databases)

Comment: would this work for more of the advanced tools such as: Graphing w/ relationship (one to one, one to many, etc...), Trigger feature, multiple query execution at once, Oracle, MSSQL & MySQL? Can I add my own drivers?

Comment: Squirrel SQL has some graphing capabilities, you can open multiple query windows to work concurrently, and it supports just about any database (I use it on Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL and Informix). Yes, you can add any JDBC driver (unless it's buggy). Haven't used triggers, but apparently this is also possible.

Comment: In 2019 this is still a good client, although you apparently have to manually install the drivers for each sql type (postgres, mysql, etc.). But it's not too hard now.

Answer (score 10):

I use [SQLite Database Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/) for SQLite3 currently and it's pretty useful. Works across Windows/OS X/Linux and is lightweight and fast. Slightly unstable with executing SQL on the DB if it's incorrectly formatted.

***Edit***: I have recently discovered [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/), a plugin for Firefox. Obviously you need to run Firefox, but you can close all windows and just run it "standalone". It's very feature complete, amazingly stable and it remembers your databases! It has tonnes of features so I've moved away from SQLite Database Browser as the instability and lack of features is too much to bear.

Comment: SQLite Manager has been deprecated due to the removal of the SQLite interface in FireFox.

Comment: Sqlectron is free and looks great. Fully cross-platform as well. https://sqlectron.github.io/

Answer (score 9):

For Oracle, I highly recommend the free Oracle SQL Developer

http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/index.html

The doucmentation states it also works with non-oracle databases - i've never tried that feature myself, but I do know that it works really well with Oracle

Comment: Works very well for MS SQL as well with jtds jdbc driver.

Answer (score 4):

I tried many GUI's, and the best for me continue being "SQLyog-comunity" by using wine. Is complete, is nice, and is intuitive. (and in wine work perfect)

Comment: Sqlectron is free and looks great. Fully cross-platform as well. https://sqlectron.github.io/