# Is there a "phpmyadmin" for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Something like phpmyadmin but for Ruby on Rails ?

I need an app to administrate easily my mysql database.. It's for myself. A GUI for Mysql database

Comment: You want a php app to administer Rails?

Comment: The idea of RoR (with migrations) is that you don't need phpmyadmin.

Comment: Or a Rails app to adminstrate MySQL?

Comment: Please provide more details about what you want to achieve.

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a web application to administer MySQL. I think it's ridiculous to claim that migrations remove the need to explore your database.  I use the command line, but many people feel more comfortable with a GUI, which is fair enough.

Comment: 'rails db' is all you ever really need :)

Comment: Use [activeadmin-sqlpage](https://github.com/oklas/activeadmin-sqlpage) gem - online sql active admin page instead of command line `rails db` if it seems more comfortable.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

finally, I hope, I can help you. This is my last project, because it was something what I missed for longer time.

https://github.com/robinbortlik/db_explorer

It is called DB explorer, it is application like phpMyAdmin, but written in Ruby on Rails. It is not exactly like, phpMyAdmin, because it not allow you so many configuration options. It is  simple solution for browsing your DB, searching and editing data. You can connect many databases and different types like MySQL, PostgeSQL and Sqlite3.

Lets, try it, and let me know if there is something wrong, or something what would be great to have implemented.

Here are some screenshots

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I don't know any equivalent of phpmyadmin in RoR but if you just want to consult the database used by a RoR application, you could still use phpmyadmin. It doesn't matter, the database is accessed by a RoR application.

Comment: you wouldn't want to do this, as you would probably be able to consult only. You really need something that understands relationships and how the db is setup. Plus phpmyadmin is awful

Comment: @daniel With that logic, you'd never access a database without using whatever abstraction layer is over it. That's neither realistic nor practical.

Comment: If you use active admin you'd understand better what I mean.....it's realistic and practical

Comment: @daniel, how would you create a new database in active admin? Create db users and grant permissions?

Comment: @Mark Thomas you wouldn't want that in the "rails" world. You want to administer your current database. Any change you'd still want to do them through migrations. And accessing the database(db users - permissions) you'd want to do it through the app itself using activeAdmin not the database itself. The whole point is not to access database directly, but abstract it. Phpmyadmin doesn't make sense for Rails

Comment: @daniel, you're not showing that you understand the difference between defining/editing models and administering a database.

Comment: Anything that changes the structure(not the data) or touches anything other than the data in the database you use a migration. Anything that touches data you can use ActiveAdmin. That is the rails way of doing things. Administering a database is the combination of both.

Comment: @daniel, admittedly the more you can do from migrations the better. But also you have to admit there are a few things you either need to drop to the MySQL prompt or use phpmyadmin for.

Comment: @Mark Thomas sorry I can't admit that. I did that when I was very new and it always bit me. Now I do migrations or rake task's for everything, I never touch the db directly. There might be "some" very specific database tuning that you might want to drop into the MySQL prompt to configure...but this just so uncommon and whoever does this wouldn't even ask this question.

Comment: @daniel, I'm sorry, but the fact is, in the real world, you need to have direct access to the database at some point. If you think otherwise, you're probably only dealing with little guestbooks and things that don't require much "administration".  There are entire jobs created for people who administer databases.

Comment: Maybe....we'll see in a few years. My database is not huge, but is probably bigger than most people's database's. Granted something like Stackoverflow is much larger but I still have trouble imaging that they use phpmyadmin to administer Stackoverflow.

Comment: Sure, but they almost certainly access the database on the command line or some other direct interface. There is just no way they would never have a reason to access the DB directly.

Comment: Even "planning" how to write your migrations usually requires some time spent exploring the schema and the data before you begin writing the migration.

Comment: Well I do look at the schema.db constantly, so I guess a "visualizer" for your db is worth it and if you use phpmyadmin for that then I could see being effective. My fear is that people made "changes" to the db through phpmyadmin as opposed to using migrations. ActiveAdmin only touches the "data" and it understands rails relations very well.

Comment: I'm sorry, but these comments are rife with personal opinion presented as fact and elitism. Personally, I manage a large normalized database (millions of records, dozens of related tables) and having a tool like phpMyAdmin is vital for sorting my thoughts and testing in general because it provides a simple interface to view your db and all of it's records quickly and easily. This conversation is certainly a non-issue if you're talking about a one or two table database with a few hundred records, but when you scale up you simply need tools to make your life easier. Not using them is just silly.

Answer (score 7):

Check out [**rails_admin**](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) - Not a full-featured DB admin tool, but great for basic browsing and editing

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about [ruby-db-admin@github.com](https://github.com/gazeldx/ruby-db-admin) ?

It is my project :)

Use Sequel and Sinatra.

Support PostgreSQL, Mysql, Sqlite, Oracle, MSSql, SqlAnywhere, DB2, Access etc.

[DEMO](http://ruby-db-admin.coding.io/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i absolutely agree with @thoferon about the fact that you don't have to matter about the Rails or PHP platform you work with. One solution that won't impact any of your websites, won't require any installation and configuration on a web server, is the usage of a MySQL client software on your **local** computer.

I don't know what OS do you have, but there are several MySQL clients for every OS. Three links I've found on Google :

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185/what-is-the-best-mysql-client-application-for-windows
- [The Best List Of Top MySQL Tools For Mac Users](http://mac360.com/2010/03/the_best_list_of_top_mysql_tools_for_mac_users/)
- [What is the best free SQL GUI for Linux for various DBMS systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001710/what-is-the-best-free-sql-gui-for-linux-for-various-dbms-systems)

Answer (score -4):

Active Admin, much better than phpmyadmin:

http://activeadmin.info/
http://railscasts.com/episodes/284-active-admin

Comment: ActiveAdmin serves a different purpose than phpmyadmin.

Comment: @Mark Thomas I disagree. Could you explain why? Say I have ActiveAdmin, what would phpmyadmin bring to the table?

Comment: phpmyadmin is a general-purpose db administration tool. You can create new databases, add db users, grant privileges, etc. Stuff you have to do before you can even connect via Rails.

Comment: The point is you wouldn't want to do this "things" in the Rails world. Rails is all about "The Rails Way" going any other way will bite you.

Comment: Please tell me "The Rails Way" to create a new MySQL database and user for the app to use.

Comment: Add a database migration, that is the Rails way. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Comment: @daniel, you're forgetting that you can't migrate a database before you even have database.yml configured. And there's some things you have to set up before that.

Comment: @Jesse Good point, but that still assumes you have what you need to connect to the db (e.g. a user with the correct permissions).

Comment: Use rake task's for such things. That is the Rails way. Even if you need to have something such as rake setup. Doing things in phpmyadmin is a no, no.

Comment: So you'd build your own implementation to create a user (which would need dbo privileges) as a rake task before you'd use mysql's own command line? I agree with Dave, that's a bit more dogmatic than pragmatic.

Comment: Also, `rake db:create` doesn't work if your database is on a different machine.

PhpMyAdmin is not a derivative of in-app admin facilities like ActiveAdmin, but of MySQLAdmin, a GUI interface.

Comment: Well you could use capistrano or a chef recipe to do this if you only do it once. If you have to do it multiple time you do a rake task. Doing things manually leads to errors. Also you should be able to deploy with 1 command, everything! if you ever worked in a project were this is not true, you would see this is anything but pragmatic.