# Rails gem - DB web interface

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, model

I'm developing a Rails app that has a very large DB, my objective is to find some graphic interface user-friendly (like phpmyadmin in php) that display (and can do some basics interaction as view, insert, delete) on the content presents in the database. Think that the final user doesn't know how programming in RoR.

I would like to avoid the use of some other code than RoR (no php or others).

There is a gem that does this work? 
I have searched but find nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try http://activeadmin.info/

Maybe its something you can use?

Or this helps you maybe: [Is there a "phpmyadmin" for Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554676/is-there-a-phpmyadmin-for-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: thanks for the reply, in my app I use activeadmin too for the app admin interface, but is not so flexible for large DB purpose only (I must to "manually" display all the tables that I want)

Comment: updated my post with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554676/is-there-a-phpmyadmin-for-ruby-on-rails

Comment: seems like that I was searching for! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/rails_db you can try this gem too, for your DB

Comment: thanks Igor - at the moment I don't need a tools like this anymore but this one seems pretty good! +1