# Is there any visual database editors SQL on RubyOnRails like phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a “phpmyadmin” for Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554676/is-there-a-phpmyadmin-for-ruby-on-rails)

I came from php, so I can't imaging my work without something like phpmyadmin.
Is there something like it on ROR ?

Comment: Why do you require a specific MVC framework to be used for an database admin application? What is wrong with PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: If you want to have a look at your development database I find [**labrador**](https://github.com/chrismccord/labrador) quite handy. This shouldn't be installed in your production environment though, use it strictly only for development. Other local alternatives would be [InductionApp](http://inductionapp.com/) (Mac OS X only) or some atabase explorer apps.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is DB explorer. It is an application similar to phpMyAdmin, but written in Ruby on Rails. Check it out: https://github.com/robinbortlik/db_explorer

Answer (score -3):

Try postgresql. It is open source database like mysql, you can use this as backend of your ROR applications.

Comment: That's not like phpmyadmin.

Comment: he ask similar to phpmyadmin only, not phpmyadmin ok? @DillonBenson

Comment: Much as I like Postgresql, the question is looking for a web based GUI interface to MySQL written using RoR, not a replacement for MySQL.

Comment: @PraveenKumar — Postgresql is similar to MySQL, not to PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar. You didn't get the point of his question. He didn't ask for an open source backend to use. He asked for a managment system to use for working with backends.

Comment: ok anyway sorry. @DillonBenson