# Connecting Microsoft SQL DB and MYSQL DB using Ruby Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server

How To Connect Microsoft SQL DB and MYSQL DB using  Ruby Rails

i have tryed with follwing changes in database.yml

**MSSQL Connection**

```
development:
  adapter: sqlserver
  encoding: utf8
  database: ******
  pool: 5
  host: *.*.*.*
```

**MYSQL Connection**

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: *****
  username: ****
  password: ****
  host: localhost
```

getting following **ERROR**:

> database configuration does not specify adapter

Comment: Can you try on following questions which already exist? 01)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15613646/how-can-i-connect-to-mysql-in-ruby-on-rails                                                                                             02) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194977/connect-sql-server-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: please, run rake db:create with --trace option and share output.