# Is there is any gem to manage database in the rails app like phpmyadmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have to manage database just like a 'phpmyadmin' in the existing rails application.
I have a application where admin can only manage database and database interface is just like a phpmyadmin.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a "phpmyadmin" for Ruby on Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554676/is-there-a-phpmyadmin-for-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: I think I am ask here for a gem not a rails application and the reference link is a rails app not a gem.
and its not provide all crud operation like a phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

Try to find [here](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_admin_interfaces)

I'm using ActiveScaffold gem, but the most popular is an ActiveAdmin gem