# Can you recommend a free light-weight MySQL GUI for Linux?

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I'm setting up my first development Linux box - a netbook actually.
I'm quite fond of MySQL Yog for Windows, but that's not on linux.

I've checked these two threads
[What is the best free SQL GUI for Linux (MSSQL, MySQL, Oracle, Etc…)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001710/what-is-the-best-free-sql-gui-for-linux-mssql-mysql-oracle-etc)
and [Developer tools to directly access databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721852/developer-tools-to-directly-access-databases)

I'm not interesting in something large and resource hungry (netbook) or that I have to pay for. Nor am I particularly interested in compatibility with SQL.

so, ***Can you recommend a free light-weight MySQL GUI for Linux?***

Unless someone suggests something better I'll probably just go with phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Dbeaver is also good lightweight visualizer for all OS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i suggest using [phpmyadmin](http://phpmyadmin.net)

it’s definitely the best free tool out there and it works on every system with php+mysql

Comment: Even if this question was answered properly, I will suggest **"Emma"** http://freecode.com/projects/emma ―which is an awesome lightweight application―as well.My friends who develop only java,but not PHP do not like web pages based tools such as "phpmyadmin" even if it is great tool.For such people,this comment would be helpful,as I believe.

Comment: I second Emma, is light and fast. Not many options but really handy. 
If you are on ubuntu just install it from software manager. Mysql workbench always hangs.

Comment: try  Valentina Studio Free

Answer (score 26):

Try [Adminer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adminer). The whole application is in one PHP file, which means that the deployment is as easy as it can get. It's more powerful than phpMyAdmin; it can edit views, procedures, triggers, etc.

Adminer is also a universal tool, it can connect to MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite, MS SQL, Oracle, SimpleDB, Elasticsearch and MongoDB.

You should definitely give it a try.

[image]

You can install on Ubuntu with `sudo apt-get install adminer` or you can also download the latest version from [adminer.org](https://www.adminer.org/)

Comment: 1 file php script being more powerfull than phpmyadmin? Sounds incredible. I've look https://www.adminer.org/en/phpmyadmin/ so i will give a try.

Answer (score 22):

Here are few solutions  -

- [MySql Gui tools](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/) is official ui
  from Mysql.
- You can also try [Mysql Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/workbench/)
  which is going to replace Gui Tools.
- Mysql Yog can be run on Linux using
  wine (I think they officially
  recommend this method).
- [HeidiSql](http://www.heidisql.com/) is also good option, I
  use it most of the time. It also run
  using wine on Linux. It lightest of all.
- If you are looking for web based
  solution than [phpmyadmin](http://phpmyadmin.net) is the
  solution.

Since you are already using sqlyog, I suggest you to use same on Linux as well.

Comment: On ubuntu, if you don't want to give oracle your email you can run `apt-get install mysql-workbench`

Comment: mysql-workbench worked on Debian 9 too.

Answer (score 17):

Why not try [MySQL GUI Tools](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html)? It's light, and does its job well.

Comment: This is the best answer. It can be installed by `apt install mysql-workbench` in ubuntu.

Comment: Best answer if you don't want to install php for such a simple task

Comment: `mysql-workbench` has a bug, it can't display query result, that make it almost useless.

Answer (score 7):

I really like the MySQL collection of of [GUI Tools](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html). They aren't too large or resource hungry.

There are quite a few options [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/03/25/mysql-admin-and-development-tools-round-up/) as well. Of the applications presented on that page, I like SQL Buddy - it does require a web server, however.

Comment: I'm really liking SQL Buddy too. Unless I find myself needing to go back to phpmyadmin some time soon, you'll get the win.

Answer (score 6):

[RazorSQL](http://www.razorsql.com/) for Linux / Unix.

Comment: It's not free, unfortunately

Answer (score 3):

[RazorSQL](http://www.razorsql.com) vote here too.  It is not free, but it's not expensive ($70 for a perpetual license and 1 year of free upgrades).

If you use it for work, it will pay for itself quickly.  I was jumping between MySQL GUI tools, SQL Server and Informix DBAccess, some of them through VMs because I use a Mac for development.  Having a single tool to connect to any database out there is pretty nice.  It is also highly customizable, and very reliable.